# PySpark code to query MySQL using Airflow Connection

Tags: mysql, pyspark, airflow

I am searching for PySpark code to query MySQL using Airflow Connection. I came across many articles explaining to use JDBC connector for MySQL connectivity. Is there any way to use Airflow connection and load MySQL data in PySpark Dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Airflow provides `SparkSubmitOperator` to submit spark jobs to a spark cluster, and `SparkJDBCOperator` which extends the first operator and just add the credentials from a JDBC connection as argument for the spark jobs ([source code](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/providers/apache/spark/hooks/spark_jdbc.py#L177-L219)). You can use the first one which is generic and add the arguments by your self to match the arguments name in your spark job if it already exists.

And if your question is about processing the arguments coming from `SparkJDBCOperator` or the generic one, here is an exemple:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--user", "-u", type=str, required=True)
    parser.add_argument("--password", "-p", type=str, required=True)
    parser.add_argument("--driver", "-d", type=str, required=True)
    parser.add_argument("--url", "-l", type=str, required=True)
    parser.add_argument("--table", "-t", type=str, required=True)
    args = vars(parser.parse_args())

    spark = (
        SparkSession.builder
            .appName("spark jdbc exemple")
            .config("other conf", "conf value...")
            .getOrCreate()
    )

   df = (
        spark.read
            .format("jdbc")
            .option("driver", args["driver"])
            .option("url", args["url"])
            .option("dbtable", args["table"])
            .option("user", args["user"])
            .option("password", args["password"])
            .load()
    )
```

Comment: I dont want to provide arguments to any Spark... operator. Is there any way I can use Airflow connection ID to run query like I can use in MySqlOperator. In MySqlOperator I dont provide any credentials as they are already set in Airflow connection.